# How to improve estimation if $\sigma^2$ is known

Tags: regression, model, error, linear

I'd like to ask this rather theoretical question about estimating a linear model with known $\sigma^2$ for the error term. I read that if the variance of the error terms was known, it would've been possible to know the population slopes and intercepts. Can you give me a hint on how to insert this information in the estimator? Trying to minimize $(\varepsilon'\varepsilon - \sigma^2)^2$ it's kind of messy. Is it a good direction to try $\operatorname{Var}[y] = \operatorname{Var}[x\beta] + \sigma^2$ assuming $x$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent?

Comment: Why would it be possible to know the slopes and intercept just because you know $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Are you also assuming that the $\epsilon$ are normally distributed?  If so you could do maximum likelihood (taking $\sigma^2$ as given and estimating only $\beta$).

Comment: What do you precisely mean by "improve?"

Comment: Where did you read this and what exactly was said? Can you provide a quote?

Comment: Knowledge of $\sigma^2$ will help a bit at small sample sizes  (e.g in terms of a smaller CI for a population coefficient -- at 13df for error the $t$ will give you a 10% wider CI than the normal would if you have $s=\sigma$) and hardly at all at large sample sizes.

Comment: Not really the queston, but in the case where [$\sigma=\sigma(x)$](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/heteroscedasticity/info), I believe a known variance can be used to weight the error terms in the least squares objective function?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps there's a misunderstanding of the [Gauss-Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem) taking place here. **An assumption of the Gauss-Markov theorem** is that $\mathrm{Var}\left(\epsilon_i \right) = \sigma^2 $. The best-linear unbiased estimator under the Gauss-Markov assumptions is $\hat{\mathbf{b}} = (X'X)^{-1}X'\mathbf{y}$. Observe that $\sigma^2$ doesn't enter the formula for the estimator *not* because it was assumed you didn't know $\sigma^2$. Rather, $\sigma^2$ doesn't enter the formula because it doesn't help!

If you drop the requirement that the estimator is unbiased (or otherwise deviate from the assumptions or objective of the Gauss-Markov theorem), you can get estimators that do depend on $\sigma^2$, such as the [James-Stein estimator.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator)

Answer (score 2):

Building on @dsaxton's comment, here are two scatterplots with the same errors $u$, drawn from $N(0,\sigma^2)$, $\sigma^2=4$. The first has slope $\beta=4$, the second $\beta=6$.

How do you want to use knowledge of $\sigma^2$ to pin down $\beta$ if two populations with the same $\sigma^2$ have different $\beta$?

[image]

```
sigma <- 2
beta1 <- 4
beta2 <- 6
u <- rnorm(100,sd=sigma)
x <- runif(100)
y1 <- beta1*x + u
y2 <- beta2*x + u

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x,y1,ylim=c(-4,8))
plot(x,y2,ylim=c(-4,8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I cannot find again the web site where it said something like "we do not know sigma, otherwise we could find the population intercept and slope".
I found it intriguing, I thought maybe there is some trick (by improving the estimator I meant reducing the variance of the estimator).
Thanks a lot for your time, you're very nice people,
Chris